# DateTime.TryParseExact not working as expected with format "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing, datetime-format, .net-core-2.1

I am trying to parse timestamps such as "5/10/2020 8:15:10 AM" into a DateTime object using the `DateTime.TryParseExact` function. Here is an example for how I am trying to do it:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
        "5/10/2020 8:15:10 AM",
        "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
        null,
        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal,
        out DateTime result
        ))
{
    ...
}
```

When I try to parse the timestamp using the format from the example, the function returns `false` and I just cannot find anything wrong with the format that I am using. Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: returning true for me

Comment: .Net Core 3.1 -- works fine for me, also. Returns "true" and 'result' correctly.

Comment: Tested on my VS and the code is working as expected, return true and the out parameter is correct `DateTime result; var dt = DateTime.TryParseExact( "5/10/2020 8:15:10 AM", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out result );`

Comment: This is so strange. When I try running it manually in the immediate window I get "Internal error in the C# compiler"

Comment: Works on dotnetfiddle.net: https://dotnetfiddle.net/r3UPq7

Comment: Note that it does not work on .NET Framework 4.7.2: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mNWgbf

Comment: So is this a bug or what could be the problem here? Is there an alternative I could use for parsing the timestamps? I am working with .NET Core 2.1

Comment: Not a bug; it's a difference in compiler versions. You're likely using an older compiler, which doesn't have support for the `out DateTime result` construct. Try declaring `result` separately.

Comment: @HereticMonkey No, that is not the case here. I am already using the same construct multiple times in the same code without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work for you, `AssumeUniversal` differs value based on timezone.

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
        "5/10/2020 8:15:10 AM",
        "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
        DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo,
        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal,
        out DateTime result
        ))
{
    bool fl = true;
}
```